# Search Pandas dataframe, start new search on find

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

Here's the situation - I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Col1      Stats       Values       Details
0    Item545
1                yes           5             77
2                no            13            55
3                maybe         7             44
4    Item327
5                yes           3             99
6                no            7             5
7                maybe         88            7
```

What I need to do is first search Col1, then start a new search on the Stats column.  For example, find "Item327" then from that row find "no". My end goal is this example is to add row 6 to a new array.  Then continue the search.

I've started using iterrows, but I'm stuck on doing the second search

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] == "Item327":
        ## Do another iterrows here?
        ## if row[1] == "no":
        ##     output = row

    ## Continue original iterrows
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should consider repeating the Item numbers on each rows so that for each Item id you have a unique yes, no and maybe row.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `df.to_dict()` shows - that'd make it easier for someone to copy/paste an example and provide an answer... It does look like you really should have an index of whatever Col1 and maybe Stats is though. (or just pivot the thing)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'Item545', '', '', ''], [1, '', 'yes', 5, 77], [2, '', 'no', 13, 55], [3, '', 'maybe', 7, 44]], columns=['Id', 'Col1', 'Stats', 'Values', 'Details'])
```

I would replace the blanks with NaN first and forward fill the items within Col1:

```
df = df.replace('', pd.np.nan)

df.Col1 = df.Col1.fillna(method='ffill')
```

That way you can easily search through the DataFrame:

```
res = df[(df.Col1 == 'Item545') & (df.Stats == 'no')]
```

You can then extract the content of each rows matching those criterias using:
`res.itertuples()` if you want to use NamedTuples or `res.values.tolist()`

Comment: Thanks, that is something I will keep in mind.  Unfortunately, there are some entries with sub-headings that are generic.  For example, [0, 'Item545', 'resource', '', ''] [0, 'Item327', 'resource', '', '']